# Safety of automatically updated Gnome extensions

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, safety

I was surprised to see that Gnome 3 extensions are updated automatically by Debian. Hence, I am wondering:

Which community procedures or practices make it difficult to inject harmful code in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which community procedures or practices make it difficult to inject harmful code in this way?

There's a human review process, https://gjs.guide/extensions/review-guidelines/review-guidelines.html#basics